# if null use another image in array

Tags: jquery, arrays, if-statement

I have an array of objects with an ImageUrl and a ThumbUrl.  If the ThumbUrl is null i want it replaced with the ImageUrl.  I have this but its not working:

```
$.each(results.Photos, function(i, pic){ 

    pic.ImageThumbUrl == null ? pic.ImageUrl;     

topicsPhoto.push({
        picUrl: pic.ImageUrl,
        picThumb: pic.ImageThumbUrl,
        picDescription: pic.Description
    });

});
```

Comment: What happens? do you get any kind of errors?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
pic.ImageThumbUrl = pic.ImageThumbUrl || pic.ImageUrl;
```

or just when pushing into the array:

```
topicsPhoto.push({
        picUrl: pic.ImageUrl,
        picThumb: pic.ImageThumbUrl || pic.ImageUrl,
        picDescription: pic.Description
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var photos = [
  { ImageUrl: "imageurl1.png", ImageThumbUrl: "thumburl1.png" },
  { ImageUrl: "imageurl2.png", ImageThumbUrl: "" },
  { ImageUrl: "imageurl3.png", ImageThumbUrl: null },
  { ImageUrl: "imageurl4.png" }
];

$.each(photos, function(i, photo) {
  photo.ImageThumbUrl = photo.ImageThumbUrl || photo.ImageUrl;
});

$.each(photos, function(i, photo) {
  $("#out").append("<br/>imageurl = " + photo.ImageUrl + ", imagethumburl = " + photo.ImageThumbUrl);
});
```

renders...

```
imageurl = imageurl1.png, imagethumburl = thumburl1.png
imageurl = imageurl2.png, imagethumburl = imageurl2.png
imageurl = imageurl3.png, imagethumburl = imageurl3.png
imageurl = imageurl4.png, imagethumburl = imageurl4.png
```

You can see it in action here: http://jsbin.com/ekemey/edit#javascript,html,live

Answer (score 1):

```
pic.ImageThumbUrl = (pic.ImageThumbUrl == null) ? pic.ImageUrl : pic.ImageThumbUrl;
```